# jQuery Colorbox IE7 issue with inline ajax loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7, colorbox

I'm using the jQuery colorbox plugin and it works great in Chrome, Firefox, IE 10, 9 and 8, but in IE7 the content of the colorbox is blank.  The plugin is set to use inline content, and I have divs set up on my page whose content is loaded dynamically via AJAX.  This works perfectly in all other browsers, but IE7 shows the colorbox with empty content.

Has anyone else run into an issue like this?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

**UPDATE:**

The problem is definitely related to the content in the inline divs being loaded via AJAX.  When I hard code the content, the colorbox popup shows the content correctly.  However when I load the content in the div using ajax, colorbox shows an empty popup.  I've tested that the ajax call is working correctly using a simple var test = $('#test').html(); alert(test); and the alert showed the ajax updated content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As IE7 support is being dropped for colorbox, this issue will not be corrected.